# Rails has_secure_token shorten character length

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the has_secure_token gem and I wish to shorten the token character length to 8. It is 24 by default. This is the link to the gem `https://github.com/robertomiranda/has_secure_token`

This token is associated with my Groups model. I was going through the gem's code and tried doing this in the groups_helper.rb but I had no luck. Thoughts on how to modify the token length? Apologies in advance if this is a simple fix but I am missing something here. Thanks.

```
 module GroupsHelper
  def generate_unique_secure_token
    SecureRandom.base58(4)
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with has_secure_token.

You can try other alternatives as the uniqueness gem: https://github.com/EventtusHQ/uniqueness

Then, you can do something like:

```
has_unique_field :my_token, length: 8
```